# Payment of SEVIS fee after Visa interview? Is this Possible?

Tags: visas, usa

Currently on admission into a US university. Must I pay the SEVIS fee before going for visa interview? Or can I get the US visa and then go over to pay the SEVIS fee later on?

Answer (score 12):

According to this FAQ from https://www.ice.gov/sevis/i901/faq:

> **How does the I-901 SEVIS fee payment process impact getting a visa?**
>
> If you are required to pay the I-901 SEVIS fee (for more information,
> see the section, Do I pay the fee?) and need a visa to enter the
> United States as student or exchange visitor, you must pay the I-901
> SEVIS fee before going to the United States embassy or consulate for
> your visa interview.
>
> If you are required to pay the I-901 SEVIS fee and do not pay it, your
> visa application will be denied by DOS.

There are more FAQs that say the same thing on that website. You must pay the I-901 SEVIS fee before your interview at a consulate.